# Trying to expand all values in specific rows in a dataframe that correspond to a value in another column into rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
  d s X3 X4 X5 X6
1 0 1  1  0  1  1
2 1 1  1  0  1  1
3 2 2  0  0  0  1
4 3 2  1  0  0  1
5 4 3  0  0  0  0
6 5 3  0  1  0  0
```

I want to combine the values in the X3-X6 columns into rows that correspond to the value in column s such that it looks something like:

```
      s G1    G2     G3     G4     G5     G6     G7     G8
1     1 1      1      0      0      1      1      1      1     
2     2 0      1      0      0      0      0      1      1     
3     3 0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
```

I did:

```
combined_data <- fake_data[,c(2:6)] %>% 
  melt(id = 's') %>% group_by(s) %>% 
  summarise(paste(value, collapse = ',')) %>% 
  separate("paste(value, collapse = \",\")", into = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8"))
```

It does what I want but I'm not convinced it's the best way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry again, the way I named the columns for the second data frame was kind of arbitrary.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I understand why your answer was different than me earlier. `melt` does order the `name` column while `pivot_longer` does in the same order of occurrence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pivot to 'long' format, create a group by sequence column and reshape it back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
fake_data %>% 
   # // remove the d column
   select(-d) %>% 
   # // pivot to long format
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('X')) %>% 
   # // order the columns to get the same order as melt
   arrange(s, name) %>%
   group_by(s) %>%
   # // update the name column by pasteing 'G' with sequence after grouping
   mutate(name = str_c('G', row_number())) %>%
   # // reshape to wide format
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 3 x 9
# Groups:   s [3]
#      s    G1    G2    G3    G4    G5    G6    G7    G8
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1
#2     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1
#3     3     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

#### data

```
fake_data <- structure(list(d = 0:5, s = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), X3 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X5 = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: sorry, trial was kind of a bad name for the columns. The column names were arbitrary and just correspond to the number of data points that corresponded to each of s1, s2, and s3.